# Postgresql - Returned type record does not match expected type uuid

Tags: postgresql

I have very simple function that should return few rows including the `uuid` type as the first column.

Function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.export_wizard()
  RETURNS TABLE(id uuid, my_column text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
  BEGIN
    return query select (w.id, w.my_column) from wizard w;
  END;
$function$
;
```

Table (short version):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.wizard
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    my_column text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT wizard_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

After calling the function like this: `select * from export_wizard();`

I got an error:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Returned type record does not match expected type uuid in column 1.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function export_wizard() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Change this `select (w.id, w.desc)...` to `select w.id, w.desc ...`. As the error message says you are currently returning a `record` instead of row of of types `uuid, text`.

Comment: desc is reserved word...

Comment: @Mark sorry I made that up for presentation, I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I made terrible mistake by adding (no idea why) brackets in SELECT statement as mentioned by @Adrian Klaver.
Correct: `return query select w.id, w.my_column from wizard w;`